# Dayjs Calendar returns wrong format

Tags: javascript, calendar, dayjs

I'm trying to replace moment.js in my work project and ran on an issue recently,
here is a code that returns a wrong output

```
const created_at = '2020-12-23T07:28:19Z'; // today is december 30th
const tzIdentifier = 'Asia/Novosibirsk';
const calendar_options = {
  sameDay: '[Today at] h:mm A',
  nextDay: '[Tomorrow at] h:mm A',
  nextWeek: 'dddd [at] h:mm A',
  lastDay: '[Yesterday at] h:mm A',
  lastWeek: '[Last] dddd [at] h:mm A', 
  sameElse: 'DD/MM/YYYY' 
}

day(created_at).tz(tzIdentifier).calendar(null, calendar_options); // always returns sameElse but there should be lastWeek
```

timezone doesn't make a difference because `day(created_at).calendar(null, calendar_options);` still returns sameElse format

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`dayjs.tz(created_at, tzIdentifier).calendar(dayjs.tz(tzIdentifier), calendar_options)`